# Swift 3 change the color of a button by pressing another button

Tags: swift3

I can manipulate all kinds of label qualities with buttons, but I want change the color of multiple buttons by pressing a reset button. Can't for the life of me get any code to work.

My example:
firstButton is white text. 
secondButton is white text. 
When I press resetButton, I want firstButton and secondButton to change text color to red.

Swift 3, xcode 8.

PS; I have no trouble changing a button color when it itself is pressed - using IBAction.

Comment: Have you tried making the buttons into a group and then iterate through them changing the buttons when the reset is pressed?

Comment: I could that, but the setTitleColor command doesn't work, other than using sender on it's own IBAction.

Answer (score 2):

Use a property per button via `IBOutlet`s, so you can reach them at any time:

```
class myClass {
    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var my2ndButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func didPressResetButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        myButton.setTitle("Hello Tint", for: .normal)
        ...
        resetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ie. resetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)

Comment: Thanks shallowThought, you certainly set me in the right direction. I've got the code to work. There were multiple errors which I've discovered. New to Swift 3 so thanks for your great help.

Comment: You are welcome. Instead of saying "thanks" in a comment you better accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    //link the buttons to change here
    @IBOutlet var buttonsToChange: [UIButton]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func resetPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {

        for b in buttonsToChange
        {
            b.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might try this in the 2nd iteration of the program. For efficiency I really should use a loop to iterate through the commands. Presently I have programmed each step individually; not the best, but I got it to work. Thanks so much for your input.